# How to change only time while keeping the date same in timestamp type

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have timestamp column used for scheduling calendar events. I would like to change only the time part while retaining the date part untouched.

How can I possibly do it? I'm on postgresql

Current:

```
2017-07-01 00:00:00
```

To:

```
2017-07-01 17:00:00
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't meaningfully change the time relatively in either direction (forward, or backwards) **without potentially impacting the date.** Timestamp is a hybrid of both date and time realizing that the two are inseparable in any real world instance. You can not go from `2017-07-01 00:00:00` to `2017-07-01 17:00:00` in a safe fashion through incrementing the time. If you try it, you're making an assumption about what the date was. However, you can *set* the time portion of a timestamp, dropping the date portion entirely with [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html). In this method, you ensure what the time portion is set as (or at least with far more certainty). So long as you don't specifically force a explicit rollover (like adding 25 hours) when you're setting it, you should be good. I see two questions here:

- How do I relatively increment a timestamp, irrespective of rollover?
- How do I set a time portion of a timestamp?

Here is some code showing both approaches

```
SELECT
  mydate + '7 hours'  AS "+7 hours",
  mydate + '17 hours' AS "+17 hours",
  date_trunc('day', mydate) + '17:00:00' AS "setting to 17 hours",
  date_trunc('day', mydate) + '25:00:00' AS "setting to 25 hours"
FROM (VALUES ('2017-07-02 10:00:00'::timestamp))
  AS t(mydate);

      +7 hours       |      +17 hours      | setting to 17 hours | setting to 25 hours 
---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 2017-07-02 17:00:00 | 2017-07-03 03:00:00 | 2017-07-02 17:00:00 | 2017-07-03 01:00:00
(1 row)
```

Aside from datetime math, think `$time=17`, vs `$datetime+=17`. One of them is far safer and less likely to create roll over. Do you want to *increment* the current column at whatever it may be by 17 hours, or *set* it to `17:00:00` on that day?

Comment: `date_trunc('day', mydate) + interval '17hr'` gives more freedom.

Comment: And what if I need to change only one part (e.g. hours), preserving other parts of date-time (days, minutes, seconds etc.)? Is it possible in postgresql?

Answer (score 7):

Add the desired INTERVAL

```
select date + interval '5 hour'
```

Have a look at: [Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) on Postgres documentation.

```
select a.MyDate + interval '5 hour' as Result_Date
from (select '2017-07-01 00:00:00'::date myDate) a

|result_date        |
|:------------------|
|2017-07-01 05:00:00|
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2f34c6fbc59147884ec7c8de540c8ba3)*

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to cast to date then back to timestamp

```
SELECT date::DATE::TIMESTAMP + interval '5 hour'
```

This ensures date is preserved